# Is there a test of a Github snippet integration on meta?

Tags: support, code-formatting, hyperlinks, markdown-rendering, github

When reading a hot meta topic, I noticed that a mere link to a line of source code in a Github repository shows up as a preview of that code.

This is what it looks like on the main page:

> [image: two paragraphs, a line of text and a line with a hyperlink]

This is what it looks like on meta:

> [image: a paragraph with the same line of text, followed by a fancy table with the link, a github icon and prominent file name/path, as well as a rendering of the linked lines]

What's going on here? Is this a secret A/B-test? Did I miss an announcement?

Comment: @Laurel Oh my, I'm getting old. I didn't miss the announcement, I just forgot about it - and I doesn't show up in a [search for github](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=github). Probably I had not realised it was enabled on meta, not just for teams.